# Passing a set of user entered data to another area of a form

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I created two tables. The first is for the mailing address (mailing street, city and etc). The second table is for the shipping address. The fields are almost the same as the mailing address. Lets assume the shipping address is same as the mailing address. How can I create a radio button which will copy the data in the first table to the second table?

The data entered by the user will saved in a MySQL database.

Can anyone show me how this can be done? Here's what I have tried so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function data_copy(){
    if(document.form1.copy[0].checked){
        document.form1.txtmailing_add2.value=document.form1.txtmailing_add1.value;          document.form1.Address.txtother_street.value=document.form1.Address.txtmailing_street.value;
        document.form1.Address.txtother_city.value=document.form1.Address.txtmailing_city.value;        document.form1.Address.txtother_state.value=document.form1.Address.txtmailing_state.value;
        document.form1.Address.txtother_postcode.value=document.form1.Address.txtmailing_postcode.value;          document.form1.Address.txtother_country.value=document.form1.Address.txtmailing_country.value;
    }
    else{
        document.form1.Address.txtmailing_add2.value="";
        document.form1.Address.txtother_street.value="";
        document.form1.Address.txtother_city.value="";
        document.form1.Address.txtother_state.value="";
        document.form1.Address.txtother_postcode.value="";
        document.form1.Address.txtother_country.value="";
    }
}

</script>

<form name=form1 method=post action="">
</form>
```

Comment: I think,
you can use javascript when radio button clicked, pass the value of the mailing address to shipping address and store the values in the table

Comment: I try use javascript to solve it. but no work.

Comment: ok then check the condition in onSubmit. If check box or option box is selected then add the value of the mailing address to both the table.

Comment: i upload my code d. can help mw take a look, what think i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function data_copy() {

    // assuming naming conventions are consistent.
    var fieldIDs = ['street', 'city', 'state', 'postcode', 'country'];

    var copy = document.getElementsByName('copy'); //using name attribute for reference

    if (copy[0].checked) {

        // note we are expecting the 'id' attribute to be set for the elements.
        var txtmailing_add1 = document.getElementById('txtmailing_add1');
        var txtmailing_add2 = document.getElementById('txtmailing_add2');

        // make sure we have valid objects before accessing their properties
        if (txtmailing_add1 && txtmailing_add2) {
            txtmailing_add2.value = txtmailing_add1.value;
        }

        // for the remaining fields we can look our field id list and generate an id 
        // by combining the expected convention with the given unique string
        for (var j = 0; j < fieldIDs.length; j++) {                
            var mailingField = document.getElementById('txtmailing_' + fieldIDs[j]);
            var otherField = document.getElementById('txtother_' + fieldIDs[j]);
            if (mailingField && otherField) {
                otherField.value = mailingField.value;
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        // same process, just skipping the 'mailing' fields
        var txtmailing_add2 = document.getElementById('txtmailing_add2');

        if (txtmailing_add2) {
            txtmailing_add2.value = '';
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < fieldIDs.length; j++) {
            var otherField = document.getElementById('txtother_' + fieldIDs[j]);
            if (otherField) {
                otherField.value = '';
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" onsubmit="data_copy();">
copy: <br />
<input type="radio" name="copy" value="1" /> yes<br />
<input type="radio" name="copy" value="0" /> no<br />
<!-- form fields -->
</form>
```